# Ignore some nested items in Gson Deserializing

Tags: json, kotlin, gson, deserialization, fuel

I want to deserialize NASA asteroids that I get from an API call in json format like this:
[image]

```kotlin
 data class Asteroid(
    val id: Int,
    val name: String = "",
    val meanDiameter: Int,
)

 class Deserializer : ResponseDeserializable<Asteroid> {
            override fun deserialize(content: String) = Gson().fromJson(content, Asteroid::class.java)
 }
```

How can I ignore the first top items `links` and `page` and only deserialize `near_earth_objects` in my Asteroid data class? And how can I access the nested items inside of `near_earth_objects`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just ignore them.

```
data class NearEarthObjects(@SerializedName("near_earth_objects") val nearEarthObjects: List<Objects>)
data class Objects(val id: String, val name: String)
```

If you then fetch the json you can just do this:

```
Gson().fromJson(yourJson, NearEarthObjects::class.java)
```

And you will get a list of all the objects name and id.

Comment: Can you elaborate on how the WhatYouNeedToGet Class should look like?